# Fixed point of matrix

Tags: matrices, reference-request, fixed-point-theorems

Suppose that $a$ is a fixed point of matrix $A$, what that means? What is a fixed point of matrix?

Thank you!

Comment: Could it be a vector $\bf a$ such that $(1,\bf {a})$ is an eigenpair for $A$?

Answer (score 2):

It is an eigenvector with an eigenvalue of 1, i.e. a vector $a$ such that $Aa=a$.