# Understanding a proof by R.C Lyndon and J.L Ullman.

Tags: group-theory, matrices

[Here](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/michigan-mathematical-journal/volume-15/issue-2/Pairs-of-real-2-by-2-matrices-that-generate-free/10.1307/mmj/1028999969.full) in this article I have difficulties understanding the theorem on page 162.

> **Theorem.** Let $A, B$ and $C=AB$ be real unimodular $2$-by-$2$ matrices $SL_2(\mathbb{R})$, all with real fixed points. Suppose that the fixed points of  each of these matrices under action on the extended real axis ${\mathbb{R}}^{*}$, lie in an interval of  ${\mathbb{R}}^{*}$ containing no fixed point of the other two.
> Then $A$ and $B$ generate a free group.

> **Proof.** First, we change the notation by replacing $B$ by $B^{-1}$. The hypothesis now asserts that $C=AB^{-1}$ has real fixed points, that is, points $p$ such that $pA=pB$. If A has distinct fixed points, one is a source $a^-$ and one is a sink $a^+$; if $A$ is parabolic, we take $a^-=a^+$ to be its sole fixed point. We employ similar notation $b^-$ and $b^+$ for fixed points of $B$. The points $a^-, \ a^+, \ b^-$ and $b^+$ divide ${\mathbb{R}}^{*}$ into four open intervals(some possibly empty). The hypothesis requires that both fixed points (possibly coincident) of $C$ lie in same one of these intervals, and not in one bounded by two fixed points of $A$ or by two fixed points of $B$.

> If $p\in (a^+,b^+)$, then $pA\in (a^+,p )$ and $pB\in (p,b^+)$. Since $(a^+,p )\cap (p,b^+)=\emptyset$, it is impossible that $pA=pB$. Thus, no fixed point of $C$ lies in an interval  $(a^+,b^+)$, or, similarly in an interval $(b^+,a^+)$.
> (The proof continuous...)

Problems that I have:

1. What is fixed point of matrix mentioned there?
2. I don't understand the second paragraph in the proof.

> > If $p\in (a^+,b^+)$, then $pA\in (a^+,p )$ and $pB\in (p,b^+)$. Since $(a^+,p )\cap (p,b^+)=\emptyset$, it is impossible that $pA=pB$. Thus, no fixed point of $C$ lies in an interval  $(a^+,b^+)$, or, similarly in an interval $(b^+,a^+)$.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Check [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/478079/fixed-point-of-matrix#comment1029499_478079) recent question.

Comment: You should type the theorem and proof into the question.

Comment: @GitGud: Did that...

Comment: Please don't double-post

Comment: See [this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/478608/understanding-a-proof-by-r-c-lyndon-and-j-l-ullman#comment10147626_478608) for the explanation of my edits.