# Understanding a proof by R.C Lyndon and J.L Ullman

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

[Here](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/michigan-mathematical-journal/volume-15/issue-2/Pairs-of-real-2-by-2-matrices-that-generate-free/10.1307/mmj/1028999969.full) in this article I have difficulties understanding the theorem on page 162.

> **Theorem.** Let $A, B$ and $C=AB$ be real unimodular $2$-by-$2$ matrices $SL_2(\mathbb{R})$, all with real fixed points. Suppose that the fixed points of  each of these matrices under action on the extended real axis ${\mathbb{R}}^{*}$, lie in an interval of  ${\mathbb{R}}^{*}$ containing no fixed point of the other two.
> Then $A$ and $B$ generate a free group.

> **Proof.** First, we change the notation by replacing $B$ by $B^{-1}$. The hypothesis now asserts that $C=AB^{-1}$ has real fixed points, that is, points $p$ such that $pA=pB$. If A has distinct fixed points, one is a source $a^-$ and one is a sink $a^+$; if $A$ is parabolic, we take $a^-=a^+$ to be its sole fixed point. We employ similar notation $b^-$ and $b^+$ for fixed points of $B$. The points $a^-, \ a^+, \ b^-$ and $b^+$ divide ${\mathbb{R}}^{*}$ into four open intervals(some possibly empty). The hypothesis requires that both fixed points (possibly coincident) of $C$ lie in same one of these intervals, and not in one bounded by two fixed points of $A$ or by two fixed points of $B$.

> If $p\in (a^+,b^+)$, then $pA\in (a^+,p )$ and $pB\in (p,b^+)$. Since $(a^+,p )\cap (p,b^+)=\emptyset$, it is impossible that $pA=pB$. Thus, no fixed point of $C$ lies in an interval  $(a^+,b^+)$, or, similarly in an interval $(b^+,a^+)$.
> (The proof continuous...)

Problems that I have:

1. What is fixed point of matrix mentioned there?
2. I don't understand the first line in second paragraph in the proof.

> If $p\in (a^+,b^+)$, then $pA\in (a^+,p )$ and $pB\in (p,b^+)$.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: You have misquoted a sentence: not "if $A \in SL_2(\mathbb Z)$" but "if $A$ is parabolic". Answer to 1: fixed points under the action of $GL_2(\mathbb Z)$ by fractional linear transformations. Answer to 2: On $\mathbb R$, draw four points as described, let $A$ act, all points outside of $a^-$ are attracted to $a^+$, the rest follows. Some standard text on hyperbolic geometry and isometries would help.

Comment: Pardon me, but I still have trouble with 2. I have all the four fractional linear transformations: $T_A(x),T_B(x), T_{C_{+}}$ and $T_{C_{-}}(x)$. But these inequalities are killing me. Moreover, in the text, how come that the four fixed points divide ${\mathbb{R}}^{*}$ into four open intervals? There are five of them, no?

Comment: The fractional linear action of $SL_2(\mathbb Z)$ is on $\mathbb R^* = \mathbb R\cup \infty$, the one point compactification of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Actually, its there already.

Comment: Thank you! You helped me a lot!

Comment: The OP managed to slightly misquote both the statement of the theorem and parts of the proof, inadvertently modifying their mathematical meaning. Unfortunately, it seems that these inaccuracies have made their way into at least one large language model (Google Bard). I have fixed the text to make the quotations accurate. Let's hope this will be a transient problem.